# How to know async request has completed response.

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, scroll, scrollbar

I have following code to append my result on scroll down in main page.

I used Graph in load data page. It takes time to load data on html page. 
Sometimes before the append data without the Graph, I tried to sync ajax call also but it blocks my browser.
How can I manage the `mytestfuntion()` to be called after the data loaded or get complete response.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var j = $.noConflict(); 
    j(window).scroll(function(){
        if  (j(window).scrollTop() == j(document).height() - j(window).height()){
            mytestfuntion();  
        }
    }); 
});


function mytestfuntion() 
{ 
    var ID=$(".prodDivDtlClass:last").attr("id");   
    $('#last_productDiv_loader').html("<img src='......./loading.gif'>");   
    var prdResultArr = $("#prdResultArr").val();
    var recfrom = $("#recfrom").val();  
    var url="loaddata.php?action=get&last_prd_id="+ID+"&recfrom="+recfrom+"&prdResultArr="+prdResultArr;

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != "") {
            var newRecfrom = parseInt(recfrom) + 10;
            $("#recfrom").val(newRecfrom);
            $(".content").append(data);
            $('#last_productDiv_loader').empty();       
        }       
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jQuery built in function [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) This function can be used to update the user that ajax request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

After run you page.

Use Firbug in Mozilla & press F12 then click on net menu.

it will shows all requests & responses.